# Well-definition of direct product of an arbitrary collection of groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

I came across this question after reading some materials about the Axiom of Choice:

> Let $I$ be any nonempty index set and let $(G_i,\star_i)$ be a group for each $i\in I$. The direct product of the groups $G_i$, $i\in I$ is the set $G=\prod_{i\in I} G_i$ with a binary operation defined as follows: if $\prod a_i$ and $\prod b_i$ are elements of $G$, then $$\bigg(\prod_{i\in I}a_i\bigg)\bigg(\prod_{i\in I}b_i\bigg)=\prod_{i\in I}a_i\star_ib_i$$
>   i.e., the group operation in the direct product is defined componentwise.
>   
> **(a)** Show that this binary operation is well-defined...
>   (Abstract Algebra: Dummit & Foote, Direct products, Ex. 15)

What do I have to show here? Is this definition not well enough? Do I have to invoke the definition of a binary operation $\star:G\times G\rightarrow G$ and show that $\prod_{i\in I}a_i\star_ib_i\in G$?

Comment: I agree there doesn't seem to be much to show here.  The axiom of choice says that since the $G_i$ are all nonempty, so is $\prod\limits_{i \in I} G_i$.  By definition, a group has to be nonempty.  Maybe that's what they have in mind for the exercise?

Comment: There's no quotient involved, hence no *well*-definedness in question. At best, an argument about well-definiedness would go along "let $x\in\prod G_i$; then there exist $a_i\in G_i$ such that $x=\prod a_i$; if there are also different $a_i'\in G_i$ with $x=\prod a_i'$, then ...", but that'd be stupid because the $a_i$ are by definition unique

Comment: @D_S You do not need choice. $\prod e_i\in\prod G_i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being asked to show that it is essentially a "unique assignment." Which is to say, if $(\prod a_i)(\prod b_i)$ can only be one thing. However, here there is not a lot to show, since if you assume that two products of elements are different, then they result in different elements in the product, almost by definition.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752937/coset-multiplication-giving-a-well-defined-binary-operation) is a similarly worded question for quotients.

Regarding you last statement, **no**, since your assertion is false. You may want to show that
$$\prod_{i \in I} a_ib_i \in \prod_{i \in I}G_i$$ as a set, but this is immediate, since $a_i b_i \in G_i$ since each of these $G_i$ are groups in their own right.